# What's .sol address?

Tags: sol

I'm trying to sign up for the weekly NFT mailing list with my .sol address.
I type my Phantom address but this error shows up.

> Please provide a valid .sol address.

Is the Phantom address different from .sol address?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably UI is requesting a Solana domain, you can get one in Bonfida
https://naming.bonfida.org/

Basically acts the same way as a DNS works, as the DNS is a mask for an IP, in Solana your SNS points to your wallet address.